# Network Manager Applet menu freezes and does not respond

Tags: network-manager, menu, freeze

Since the latest update in Ubuntu 10.10, the nm-applet has started doing some strange things. I boot up the PC, all is fine, internet works, etc... but after a period of time, approx and hour, the nm-applet menu in the Gnome panel fails to respond. when I click on the icon, the menu appears, all looks well, but when I select any option, eg DISCONNECT, nothing happens. Even the VPN sub menu disappears (no triangle to select the menu.) However I do not lose the network connection...

If I Run this script:

killall nm-applet

/etc/init.d/NetworkManager restart

nm-applet

all returns as normal, for a while... weird?

i tried uninstall/reinstall... I even reinstalled Ubuntu, but once the latest updates are applied this issues arises...

Any help?

Comment: I am using: Ubuntu 10.10, Kernel 2.6.35-24-generic-pae, 4GB Ram DDR2, Intel Quad Core Processor. I am wondering if this strange error has anything to do with the quad core processor, I did have random errors using a quad core with Ubuntu on previous versions, but a dual core worked without a hitch... a bit random, but I'll try changing the processor later.. worth a shot...

Comment: Same does happen on my other PC's and laptops too....

Comment: If I kill the nm-applet in terminal and then run again, the nm-applet runs but the terminal displays this continuously:                                                                           (nm-applet:17694): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_image_get_storage_type: assertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed

(nm-applet:17694): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nm-applet:17694): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Comment: (nm-applet:17694): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_image_get_storage_type: assertion `GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed

(nm-applet:17694): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nm-applet:17694): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Comment: I'm experiencing the same in **NATTY** (and was looking for a way to kill / restart it). Further, on my university's wpa-enterprise network, I'm experiencing [frequent wlan disconnects/hangs/delays](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47494/need-instructions-on-how-to-create-wpa-supplicant-conf-and-add-fast-reauth-0-to-i). Is your method to kill / restart "official"? Are there other ways? e.g. using system monitor gui: kill, stop, continue & end process? How? Which processes exactly? (Just curious, and eager to learn)

Comment: Killing and running `nm-applet` works, thank you very much. I had to use `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain sources (notably Elementary Desktop's PPA) have a version of network-manager-gnome which is newer than the one in the canonical maverick repository.  A fix has been issued for Natty, but is not in the Maverick repos yet.  So Ubuntu sees the newer version in elementary-desktop, uses that instead of the canonical one and, hence, the bug.

The solution is to roll back the version of network-manager-gnome to the 0.8.1+git.20100809t190028.290dc70-0ubuntu3 from 0.8.2+git.20101123t161608.f143e76-0ubuntu1

This can be done from synaptic by searching for network-manager-gnome and then clicking 'force version' in the package menu and selecting the 0.8.1 version.

Comment: How do I downgrade this package? "Force version" is greyed out in Synaptic. When I try `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome=0.8.1+git.20100809t190028.290dc70-0ubuntu3`, I get the error `Version ‘0.8.1+git.20100809t190028.290dc70-0ubuntu3’ for ‘network-manager-gnome’ was not found`. By the way I have version `0.8.4~git.20110318t152954.9c4c9a0-0ubuntu1`

Comment: I still have this problem in Precise.  How can I check which, if any PPA's might be causing the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

No need to force it anymore, that have taken 0.82 out. So just downgrade, no need to lock.