# nm-applet freeze in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, network-manager

I have the same problem as [Network Manager Applet menu freezes and does not respond](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23611/network-manager-applet-menu-freezes-and-does-not-respond) in ubuntu 12.04.
Now, even restarting the nm-applet won't help.
Is it a bug? I thought 12.04 would be pretty stable now.
What could I do then？
Thanks!

Comment: Please file a bug report in Launchpad against the network-manager-applet package.

Comment: @jdthood it's already there https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/930563

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). *This comment is for reference*

Answer (score 1):

I think I am still having a similar bug on my 12.04 LTS system.  For now, restarting nm-applet works for me, as described in [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1006141/comments/5).

```
alex@alex-desktop:~$ ps -A | grep nm-applet
21903 ? 00:00:00 nm-applet
alex@alex-desktop:~$ kill 21903
alex@alex-desktop:~$ nohup nm-applet &
[1] 22476
alex@alex-desktop:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
alex@alex-desktop:~$
```

Certainly this is not a fix, but it's a quick way to get nm-applet working again (for me).  In fact, when I'm lazy, I can just start a new instance of nm-applet without killing the old one.  Maybe someone call tell me why that's a dangerous idea, but for now it's helping!